# Different unittest.mock behavior on Python 2/3

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have the unittest that should be compatible with both python 2 and 3. It looks like that:

```
def test_getModulePath_BuildInThrowsAnException(self):
    resource = mock.Mock(spec=some.module.SomeClass)
    resource.name = 'BuiltIn'
    resource.parent = resource

    if sys.version_info[0] == 3:  # Python 3
        patched_class = '_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader'
    else:  # Python 2
        patched_class = 'pkgutil.ImpLoader'

    with mock.patch(patched_class) as loader_mock:
        loader_mock.side_effect = MyException
        try:
            result = MyClass._get_module_path(resource)
            self.assertIsNone(result)
        except MyException as e:
            self.fail(e)
```

The method i want to test:

```
@classmethod
def _get_module_path(cls, resource):
    ...
    try:
        loader = pkgutil.get_loader(resource.name)
    except MyException as e:
        return None
    ...
    return loader.get_filename()
```

The problem is that `pkgutil.get_loader()` returnes different objects which depends on python version. On Py2 everything is ok, loader raises an error as side_effect, method returnes None and `loader_mock.called = True`.
But on Py3 loader side_effect doesn't work and method goes to `return loader.gt_filename()`.
Any ideas?
Python version: 2.7.15 and 3.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the problem is related with python import system, because the object returned by `get_loader` is exectly a `_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader`, but `side_effect` is not raised.
The problem was solved by patching `pkgutil.get_loader` function, not the return object class:

```
        with mock.patch('pkgutil.get_loader', side_effect=MyException):
            try:
                result = MyClass._get_module_path(resource)
                self.assertIsNone(result)
            except MyException as e:
                self.fail(e)
```

I hope this will help someone. Thanks.